# Google search : pubdate issue

Tags: seo, google, html5, search, googlebot

At some point this year, **Google Search** started to show the **publication date**.

When I updated my website, I noticed that the publication date was actually my birthday, simply because it's the first date **googlebot** encounters.

I can't delete it because it would defy the whole *"My website is my Resume"* idea.

I tried to solve the problem by wrapping it in **address** tag and putting the date in **time** tag with **datetime** attribute, but it didn't work out.

```
<address>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Porte à Camp 5 <br/>
            7971 Basècles <br/>
            BELGIQUE
        </li>
        <li> 
            <time datetime="1984-01-29">29/01/1984</time><br/>
            Belge/Russe
        </li>
        <li>
            +32 (0)493/.49.18.23<br/>
            <span id="mail">razine.ivan</span> | 
            <a href="http://bit.ly/qzITgb" class="red">Télécharger CV</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</address>
```

So far, the only way I could solve it is by deleting **q=show+the+publication+date** from the url.

I have no clue how to fix that. Any ideas?

This is my web page: [ivanrazine.be](http://ivanrazine.be/)

And this is the search result (4th position): [google search](http://www.google.be/search?gcx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=show%20the%20publication%20date#sclient=psy-ab&hl=fr&source=hp&q=ivan%20razine&pbx=1&oq=ivan%20razine&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=475812l478047l1l478488l11l9l0l2l2l0l313l1644l0.5.3.1l11l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=61fa2ed69673156b&biw=1280&bih=728)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the meta-tag `last updated` like that:

```
<meta name="last_updated" content="2001-08-28">
```

Comment: waiting for googlebot to confirm, but that seems right, thanks!